# Corcel : How to form a many-to-many relationship between WordPress tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, eloquent, corcel

I use **Laravel 7** with **[Corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel)** to connect to the database of a **WordPress** installation.

The connection works fine, no problems fetching data from WordPress so far:
`App\Project::where('id',3)->get();` ✔️
`App\Tester::where('id',4)->get();`  ✔️

In my WordPress installation there are additional tables used by a project management plugin called [WP Project Manager](https://wedevs.com/wp-project-manager-pro/). I want to form a many-to-many relationship between a wordpress table (WP: **users**) and a plugin table (WP-Plugin: **pm_projects**) via a pivot table (WP-Plugin: **pm_role_user**).

The plugin's pivot table has four fields: **project_id**, **role_id**, **assigned_by** and **user_id**. It connects the users with the projects.

So I created the models **Project** and **Tester** (in my context a User is regarded to be a Tester) like this:

### Project.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Corcel\Model as Model;

class Project extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'pm_projects';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'status',
        'budget',
        'pay_rate',
        'est_completion_date',
        'color_code',
        'order',
        'projectable_type',
        'completed_at',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'est_completion_date'
    ];

    public function testers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tester::class, 'pm_role_project_users', 'role_project_id', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

### Tester.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Corcel\Model\User as User;

class Tester extends User
{

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'pm_role_project_users', 'user_id', 'role_project_id');
    }

}
```

When I try to get a users projects with `App\Project::where('id',3)->testers()->get();`, I get the following error message:

> *BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder::testers()'*

My question:
How can I make many-to-many connections between my WordPress tables in Laravel, using Corcel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App\Project::where('id',3) is a eloquent query builder instance, not eloquent element. You should use `first()` method first then your model method/relation. So the code should be like:

```
App\Project::where('id',3)->first()->testers()->get();
```

but it can be simply(and you should use this):

```
App\Project::where('id',3)->first()->testers;
```

It's will return testers collection from project 3.

Comment: or use `with` to load relationship.